# How can I go about uploading and receiving a users profile picture?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, user-profile

So far in my social media app, the user's data such as first name, last name, email, gender, and more can be saved in a firebase database and retrieved when needed. As of today, I got a working profile picture when first creating a profile you can tap on the empty profile picture icon and it loads up your gallery replacing it with whatever image the user chooses.

Although this is quite neat I need to be able to upload this image somehow under the Users node in my firebase database. I am quite lost when it comes to converting the bitmap data and after reading through some documentation it still confuses me. Below is my code for using a locally saved photo replacing it as the profile picture to show what I have so far.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if (view == profilePicture)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "We made it to the onClick for image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri targetUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try
        {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
            profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The onClick method runs after the user taps the profile icon. Now I will show you the database I am currently working with, this is the Firebase real-time database, not the Firebase storage. While firebase storage might be more appropriate I can't seem to figure out how to tell whos photo would be who as it does not upload them with a user id associated with them.

[Database Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzTJw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of uploading a bitMap, a far better solution for a simple problem like yours would be Firebase Storage, similar to the Database but you can upload files such as images with much ease.

Here are the methods I currently use in my app:

```
private void chooseImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

private void uploadImage() {

    if(filePath != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+userID);
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        toastMessage("Uploaded");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        toastMessage("Failed"+e.getMessage());
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: That helps me significantly, Thank you so much! And I noticed you are putting it under a images node.userId so when receiving this data you just have to point to the same directory.

My only question is in chooseImage() method where you set the type to "image/*" how exactly is that working. Also, how does that method know to fire off upload image or is that happening where I cannot see. I understand that startActivityForResult has more utility than just startActivity but it confuses me with how it works. Thank you again for everything!

Comment: The chooseImage method creates a new intent (kinda like a screen) of type "image" (which is the gallery itself), and gives the result as an image chosen, so it basically opens the gallery. You can call it on a button or an imageView click listener for example, and then do the same to upload the image to the firebase, another button perhaps. This guide is very well suited for what you are searching: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-upload-to-firebase-in-android-application--cms-29934
 Good luck with it.